# R sampling command size not correct

Tags: r

```
ratio[i]
```

[1] 0.9

```
length(sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),2000*ratio[i],replace=T))
```

[1] 1800

```
length(sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),2000*(1-ratio[i]),replace=T))
```

[1] 199

It looks like R is doing the calculation incorrectly. I tried a few more number, sometimes it is correct, but sometimes it is not. So I did the following.

```
space<-matrix(nrow=10000,ncol=2)
for (i in 1:10000){
#expected
  space[i,1]<-20000*(1-i/10000)
#actual
  space[i,2]<-length(sample(1,20000*(1-i/10000),replace=T))

}

plot(space[,1]-space[,2])
```

It appears that this problem is not limited to a few numbers.

Comment: Also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the imprecision of floating point operations. `2000*(1-ratio[i])` does not give *exactly* 200 as you can see if you do this:

```
options(digits=22)
2000*(1-ratio[i])

[1] 199.9999999999999431566
```

You get the same result if you do `2000 * (1 - 0.9)`.

`sample` uses the floor of `size` parameter and floor of 199.9999...566 is 199. You can wrap it in `round()` to make sure you get the sample size you were expecting.

Comment: agreed. Although is it not a bug in `sample` to use `floor` instead of `round` ?

Comment: Well,  `sample` and (for example) `seq` and `rep` all use only the integer part of the size argument. Whether that's a bug or a feature is above my pay grade.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that 'sample' is 'flooring' argument 'size' when a double is passed.

Please ensure that you are passing an integer in argument 'size'

```
length(sample(1:9,size=2000*(1-0.9),replace=TRUE)) # length is 199
```

but

```
length(sample(1:9,size=round(2000*(1-0.9)),replace=TRUE)) # length is 200
```